# How to merge two generated tables using group by 'a' field by max of 'b' field?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, group-by, union

Have next query:

```
select `privmsgs_id`, `contact`, `privmsgs_date`, `contentType` from (
    (
        select max(`privmsgs_id`) as `privmsgs_id`, `contact`, max(`privmsgs_date`) as `privmsgs_date`, `contentType` from (
            (
                select `privmsgs_from_userid` as `contact`, `privmsgs_id`, `privmsgs_date`, 'message' as `contentType`
                    from `privmsgs_table`
                where `privmsgs_to_userid` = 305026
            ) union (
                select `privmsgs_to_userid` as `contact`, `privmsgs_id`, `privmsgs_date`, 'message' as `contentType`
                    from `privmsgs_table`
                where `privmsgs_from_userid` = 305026
            )
        ) as `tmp` group by `contact` order by `privmsgs_date` desc
    ) union (
        select max(`privmsgs_id`) as `privmsgs_id`, `contact`, max(`privmsgs_date`) as `privmsgs_date`, `contentType` from (
            (
                select `from_userid` as `contact`, `id` as `privmsgs_id`, `date` as `privmsgs_date`, 'postcard' as `contentType`
                    from `postcards_table`
                where `to_userid` = 305026
            ) union (
                select `to_userid` as `contact`, `id` as `privmsgs_id`, `date` as `privmsgs_date`, 'postcard' as `contentType`
                    from `postcards_table`
                where `from_userid` = 305026
            )
        ) as `tmp1` group by `contact` order by `privmsgs_date` desc
    )
) as `rTmp` order by `privmsgs_date` desc;
```

There are two tables `tmp` and `tmp1` merged by union, but has doubled field `contact`:

```
privmsgs_id contact privmsgs_date   contentType
21490780    7070    1315207813      message
21556868    7070    1315215266      postcard
21226460    7754    1312025735      message
21539085    15588   1314615528      postcard
21489812    15588   1315208838      message
```

So, I need only last records (message or postcard - does not matters) and id of this last record (there is the problem - i can get max(id) in messages and postcards separate, but can't do it in merged table):

```
privmsgs_id contact privmsgs_date   contentType
21556868    7070    1315215266      postcard
21226460    7754    1312025735      message
21489812    15588   1315208838      message
```

Reason, why I don't do it by simplifying query is that I need a specific number of results, so, I can do this only by one query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group the result by `contact` and select the max `privmsgd_id`, and then select the info from only those `privmsgd_id`'s.

Check [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for more info.

Comment: postcards and messages got from separated tables, so id of older postard (by date) may be less than earlier message id. There is the problem - i can't sort two different tables by different id's.

Comment: I need to get actual id by grouping records by `contact` and sorting by max(date). It is the only way to do this, but I don't know how.